# Total dates with Twig

Tags: datetime, twig

I found the difference between two dates and now I am trying to sum up all the differences. Can someone help me?

```
{% for clock in clock %}
    {% set difference = date(clock.dateTimeStart).diff(clock.dateTimeEnd).format('%H:%I:%S') %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ clock.dateTimeStart|date("d/m/Y") }}</td>
        <td>{{ clock.dateTimeStart|date("H:i:s") }} to {{ clock.dateTimeEnd|date("H:i:s") }}</td>
        <td>{{ difference }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `DateTimeInterval`'s by adding them into a `DateTime` object and testing the difference at the end again.

```
{% set total_start = date('00:00') %}
{% set total_end = date('00:00') %}

{% for range in data %}
    {% set difference = date(range.start).diff(date(range.end)) %}
    {% do total_end.add(difference) %}

    {{ difference.format('%H:%I:%S') }}
{% endfor %}

Total difference: {{ total_start.diff(total_end).format('%H:%I:%S') }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/x9oywu)